# Word Frequency from a CSV Column in Python

Tags: python

I have a .csv file with a column of messages I have collected, I wish to get a word frequency list of every word in that column. Here is what I have so far and I am not sure where I have made a mistake, any help would be appreciated. Edit: The expected output is to write the entire list of words and their count (without duplicates) out to another .csv file.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict

output_file = 'comments_word_freqency.csv'
input_stream = open('comments.csv')
reader = csv.reader(input_stream, delimiter=',')
reader.next() #skip header
csvrow = [row[3] for row in reader] #Get the fourth column only

with open(output_file, 'rb') as csvfile:
    for row in reader:
        freq_dict = defaultdict(int) # the "int" part
                                    # means that the VALUES of the dictionary are integers.
        for line in csvrow:
            words = line.split(" ")
            for word in words:
                word = word.lower() # ignores case type
                freq_dict[word] += 1

        writer = csv.writer(open(output_file, "wb+")) # this is what lets you write the csv file.
        for key, value in freq_dict.items():
                        # this iterates through your dictionary and writes each pair as its own line.
            writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: What does your output look like? Also it doesn't look like you are doing anything to get the frequency of the words. Have you tried just using a for loop and .count()?

Comment: Do you get any error message? What's the expected output? Please take a look at [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I would ideally like to have an output.csv file that has two columns, one with the words (without duplicates) and one column with the number of times that word appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you uploaded is all over the place, but I think this is what you're getting at. This returns a list of the word and the number of times it appeared in the original file.

```
words= []
with open('comments_word_freqency.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
         csv_words = row[3].split(" ")
         for i in csv_words:
              words.append(i)

words_counted = []
for i in words:
    x = words.count(i)
    words_counted.append((i,x))

#write this to csv file
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerows(edgl)
```

Then to get rid of the duplicates in the list just call set() on it

```
set(words_counted)
```

Your output will look like this:

```
'this', 2
'is', 1
'your', 3
'output', 5
```

Comment: How can I limit the search for a particular column? Would I do row[column_number]?

Comment: Just updated it. If you just use row[3] it will give you the fourth column only

Comment: I have imported csv, yet I still get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "count_word_occurrences.py", line 6, in <module>
    for row[3] in reader:
NameError: name 'row' is not defined

Comment: Well that means you haven't defined row anywhere... They way I posted it row is defined in the for loop. You can't copy and paste part of this into your old code and expect it to run. Make sure all the variable names are consistent and defined

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the packages you imported. And this code shouldn't be merged with anything, it's written to run on its own, just try running my code maybe that will help you understand whats going on here. Also maybe add 'print words_counted' because you are working from command line, just so you can see the output

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the code it is a good starting point and I will work to output those results to another .csv file now. Thank you SAMO :)

Comment: No problem, though I'm not sure what you would be missing this is literally all you need. If you just pasted this into a python file you're done. I even just uploaded how you write to a CSV. At this point you should probably select this as the correct answer as I've worked with you and rewrote your program for you

Comment: Much appreciated SAMO, I have marked your solution as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I run the code proposed by SAMO. I was facing some issues with Python3.6. Hence, I am posting a working code [changed few lines from SAMO's code], which may help others and save their times.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict

words= []
with open('data.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(reader)
    for col in reader:
         csv_words = col[0].split(" ")
         for word in csv_words:
              words.append(word) 

with open('frequency_result.csv',  'a+') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for word in words:
        word_count = words.count(word)
        words_counted.append((word,word_count))    
    writer.writerow(words_counted)
```